# Flex:Virtual Keyboard

Tags: apache-flex

How can i create a virtual(on screen) keyboard in flex?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an existing one you can use: https://github.com/GrfxGuru/Adobe-Flex-4.5-Components

Answer (score -2):

You can use my virtual keyboard component at http://divisionby0.org/portfolio/129-virtual-keyboard-flex-component.html.